# QSpinBox enter NaN as a valid value

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox

I am trying to extend the QSpinBox to be able to enter "NaN" or "nan" as a valid value. According to the documentation i should use the textFromValue, valueFromText, and validate functions to accomplish this but i cant get it to work since its still not allowing me to enter any text besides numbers.  Here is what i have in my .h and .cpp files:

CPP file:

```
#include "CustomIntSpinBox.h"

CustomIntSpinBox::CustomIntSpinBox(QWidget *parent) : QSpinBox(parent)
{
    this->setRange(-32767,32767);
}

QString CustomIntSpinBox::textFromValue(int value) const
{
    if (value == NAN_VALUE)
    {
        return QString::fromStdString("nan");
    }
    else
    {
        return QString::number(value);
    }
}

int CustomIntSpinBox::valueFromText(const QString &text) const
{
    if (text.toLower() == QString::fromStdString("nan"))
    {
        return NAN_VALUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return text.toInt();
    }
}

QValidator::State validate(QString &input, int pos)
{
    return QValidator::Acceptable;
}
```

H file:

```
#ifndef CUSTOMINTSPINBOX_H
#define CUSTOMINTSPINBOX_H

#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define NAN_VALUE 32767

class CustomIntSpinBox : public QSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomIntSpinBox(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~CustomIntSpinBox() throw() {}

    int valueFromText(const QString &text) const;
    QString textFromValue(int value) const;
    QValidator::State validate(QString &input, int pos);
};

#endif // CUSTOMINTSPINBOX_H
```

Is there something im missing? or doing wrong? If theres and easier way to do this also that would be great to know...

Comment: Some suggestions regarding your code, independent of the question: (1) Don't use throw specifications unless you must because the base class does ([Sutter/Alexandrescu](http://www.amazon.com/Coding-Standards-Rules-Guidelines-Practices/dp/0321113586), Item 75). (2) Make your ctor `explicit` (ibid, Item 40). (3) Don't write `using namespace` in a header (ibid., Item 59). (4) Use `static const int NAN_VALUE = 32767;` instead of a `#define` (ibid., Item 16). (5) Don't `#include <QtGui>` (slows down compilation). (6) Use `QLatin1String("nan")` instead of `QString::fromStdString("nan")` (faster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of `QAbstractSpinBox::validate()` is:

```
QValidator::State QAbstractSpinBox::validate ( QString & input, int & pos ) const
```

So your `validate()` method's signature differs in two ways: its not `const`, and you have `int pos` instead of `int& pos`. Thus it doesn't override `QAbstractSpinBox::validate` and is never called by `QAbstractSpinBox`.

Comment: Thank your very much! that was the problem.

Comment: if i wanted to do the same thing for QDoubleSpinBox, will this code still work? or will I have to change the functions to account for the decimal point in the text?

Answer (score 4):

If you can extend the lower bound of your range by -1 and use a normal `QSpinBox` or `QDoubleSpinBox` and call `spinbox->specialValueText("nan")`, which will show the string `nan` when `value() == minimum()`. The user won't be able to enter the string "nan" manually, but you can always accompany the spinbox with a button that executes `spinbox->setValue(spinbox->minimum())`. Here's a compilable example:

```
// main.cpp
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include <limits>

class Tester : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static const int NanValue = -32767-1;
    explicit Tester(QWidget * parent=0)
        : QDialog(parent),
          m_spinBox(new QSpinBox(this)),
          m_doubleSpinBox(new QDoubleSpinBox(this))
    {
        QVBoxLayout * vlay = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        vlay->addWidget(m_spinBox);
        vlay->addWidget(m_doubleSpinBox);

        m_spinBox->setRange(NanValue,32767);
        m_doubleSpinBox->setRange(NanValue,32767);

        m_spinBox->setValue(NanValue);
        m_doubleSpinBox->setValue(NanValue);

        updateSpecialValueText();
    }

protected:
    void changeEvent(QEvent *e) {
        QDialog::changeEvent(e);
        if (e->type() == QEvent::LocaleChange)
            updateSpecialValueText();
    }


private:
    void updateSpecialValueText() {
        static const double NaN = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
        m_spinBox->setSpecialValueText(locale().toString(NaN));
        m_doubleSpinBox->setSpecialValueText(locale().toString(NaN));
    }

private:
    QSpinBox * m_spinBox;
    QDoubleSpinBox * m_doubleSpinBox;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Tester t;
    return t.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe QSpinBox sets a lineEdit wich has a QIntValidator as QValidator. At least the docs of QAbstractSpinBox::setLineEdit suggest that the validator of the lineEdit has priority over the QAbstractSpinBox::validate function.