# Set string to QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox

Regarding some task I must do the following. 
Consider I have a QDoubleSpinBox with positive values from 0 to 1000. And every time when user tries to lower the value of spinbox, f.e. to click the down button when value is 0, the value of spinbox must be string "unset". I tried to do this, to clear the value of spinbox and then setPrefix. But it did not worked. Any other solutions?

Comment: Hm, but QDoubleSpinBox is to display floating point numbers. However you want to set a string? Maybe using a label along with the spin box would be better idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try `specialValueText`.

This is a example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDoubleSpinBox doubleSpinBox;
    doubleSpinBox.setRange(0.f, 1000.f);
    doubleSpinBox.setValue(1.f);
    doubleSpinBox.setSpecialValueText("unset");

    doubleSpinBox.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

when value is 0, the value of spinbox must be string "unset".

Comment: Nice functionality: Using Qt quite a while and never thought something like this exists. Thanks for your tip!

Comment: For those wondering, to unset this just call doubleSpinBox.setSpecialValueText("")

Answer (score 6):

There are two solutions to achieve what you want.

As pezy in the other answer says using [setSpecialValueText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#specialValueText-prop) where the text is shown when the current value() == minimum() of the spinbox

or a bit more powerful: subclass QSpinBox and override following functions:

```
int valueFromText(const QString &text) const;
QString textFromValue(int value) const;
QValidator::State validate(QString & input, int & pos) const;
```

Have a look here, trying something similar [QSpinBox enter NaN as a valid value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133336/qspinbox-enter-nan-as-a-valid-value).

Answer (score -1):

Sub class QSpinBox and define your behavior.
Take a look at this [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-icons-iconsizespinbox-cpp.html)